# How to find more Xcode project used entry?

Tags: xcode

How to find more Xcode project used entry?

Like the recent 50 project entry item.

[image: 111]

The default 9 entry item is not that charming.

I guess, Xcode read the entry info from a folder.

So the question became that where the info folder and file are , if it is as I expected.

Comment: Hi you may organize you projects with a tool. [XCOrganizer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcorganizer/id1507556912?mt=12) may be an example but there may be also other ones

Comment: very nice option